# Can a character only eat one Weapon indestructability book to get a stat upgrade?

Tags: river-city-girls

I bought some of the books from Rocko, and ate three different ones now. I'm a LV 25 Kyoko and only remember seeing the WP increase once, giving me 14 WP in total.

So is it only worth it to buy 5 books? 4 copies of each kind, and 1 to eat? A.k.a it's only worth it to eat one book, instead of all four?